# Getting the range of elements from a List in java

Tags: java, list, sorting

I have a `List<Float>` which has elements in sorted order. The elements are added to the list like this:

```
list.add(17.0);
list.add(19.0);
list.add(19.5);
list.add(20.0);
list.add(20.5);
list.add(23.0);
list.add(23.5);
list.add(34.0);
list.add(39.0);
list.add(39.5);
```

I want to extract the elements which have a difference of 0.50 in sequential order as a range. I need to convert this to a List, containing "17.0", "19.0-20.5", "23-23.5", "34", and "39-39.5". How can I do this?

Comment: First thoughts: Use a Map.

Comment: I think you can use a `for` loop to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this help:

```
List<Float> list = new ArrayList<Float>();
    list.add((float) 17.0);
    list.add((float) 19.0);
    list.add((float) 19.5);
    list.add((float) 20.0);
    list.add((float) 20.5);
    list.add((float) 23.0);
    list.add((float) 23.5);
    list.add((float) 34.0);
    list.add((float) 39.0);
    list.add((float) 39.5);

    List<String> retval = new ArrayList<String>();

    float sequenceBegin = list.get(0);
    float prev = list.get(0);
    for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) {
        float d = list.get(i);
        if (d - prev != 0.5) {
            String seqStr = "";
            if (prev == sequenceBegin) {
                seqStr += prev; // sequence has only one item
            } else {
                seqStr += sequenceBegin + "-" + prev;
            }
            retval.add(seqStr);
            sequenceBegin = d;
        }
        prev = d;
    }

    //process the last item
    String seqStr = "";
    if (prev == sequenceBegin) {
        seqStr += prev; 
    } else {
        seqStr += sequenceBegin + "-" + prev;
    }
    retval.add(seqStr);     

    System.out.println(retval);




Output: [17.0, 19.0-20.5, 23.0-23.5, 34.0, 39.0-39.5]
```

Comment: BTW, I have not already checked the case of duplicated items (i.e there are more than 1 items 17.0) . You can optimize it to make your code more reliable.

Comment: Floating point precision will play games with you. Comparing a float to another float is almost always problematic. When your values grow this could happen: `System.out.println(9999999.5f - 9999999.0f);  // 1.0  System.out.println(1.5f - 1.0f); // 0.5`

Comment: @Anthony.....for me it will never have duplicate elements as I am populating list from Set So your code is good enough for me, I have upvoted the answers . thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try below example:

```
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    List<Float> list = new ArrayList<Float>();
    list.add((float) 17.0);
    list.add((float) 19.0);
    list.add((float) 19.5);
    list.add((float) 20.0);
    list.add((float) 20.5);
    list.add((float) 23.0);
    list.add((float) 23.5);
    list.add((float) 34.0);
    list.add((float) 39.0);
    list.add((float) 39.5);

    List<List<Float>> listTmp = new ArrayList<List<Float>>();       
    List<Float> iList = null;

    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
        if(iList == null) {
            iList = new ArrayList<Float>();
            iList.add(list.get(i));
        }
        else {
            if(list.get(i) - iList.get(iList.size() - 1) == 0.5){
                iList.add(list.get(i));
                if(i == list.size() - 1){
                    listTmp.add(iList);
                }
            }
            else {
                listTmp.add(iList);
                iList = null;
                i--;
            }
        }
    }

    List<String> finalList = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(int i = 0; i < listTmp.size(); i++){
        List<Float> iiList = listTmp.get(i);
        if(iiList.size() == 1){
            finalList.add(String.valueOf(iiList.get(0)));
        }
        else {
            finalList.add(String.valueOf(iiList.get(0)) + "-" + String.valueOf(iiList.get(iiList.size() - 1)));
        }           
    }


    System.out.println(finalList);
```

Hope this help!

Comment: Hi Nam, this looks good but still it dosn't print the last range of 39 to 39.5.

Comment: I would be VERY careful with assuming that comparing floats like that would be 100% accurate

Comment: I just revise a little bit to get the full result! Please enjoy!